# Get the top n classes and the corresponding confidence level from the libSVM package

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I'm using libsvm library (https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) to classify some data.

This is the syntax that i'm using for prediction:

```
[predict_label, accuracy, prob_estimates] = svmpredict(lbpModel.labels(1,1), lbpModel.features(1,:), trainedModel);
```

From my understanding prob_estimates is computed this way: If you have the following classes : (class 1, 2, 3, 4), the algorithm does the following comparations:

1 vs. 2, 1 vs. 3, 1 vs 4, 2 vs. 3, 2 vs. 4, and 3 vs. 4.

Thus you get 6 decision values in the prob_estimates vector.

What changes should I make to the prob_estimates vector to get something like this:

```
[0.7 , 0.19, 0,2, 0,1 ....]
```

It can be translated to:
Class1 = 70%, Class2 19%, Class3 2%, Class4 1% etc.

So basically I want to extract the top 3 predicted classes and I need to know the confidence level (%). Because if I get Class1 50%, Class2 49%, Class3 1% and Class4 0%, I don't really want to label the data with the winning class, since the difference between the confidence level for the first 2 classes is too small, so I would rather label the data with both classes (I know that for most problems it doesn't make too much sense, but for my problem it does).

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to go could be to use a one-vs-all strategy instead of one-vs-one, wich is the default for libsvm.

This means if you have 4 classes, you train 4 SVMs, where each class decides, whether the sample belongs to one class or all the other classes. This way you get for each class a probability how likely it is that this sample belongs to this class.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to solve the problem with your help. The only problem that remains is that by doing this for a lot of classes (500 or etc.) it takes a lot of time. Any solution for speeding the process?

Comment: Well, you could probably easily parallelize the training of those 500 SVMs to take advantage of your multicore cpu. Do you happen to train a linear SVM? Then [liblinear](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear) would be a very fast choice.

Comment: Thank you, parfor did the trick. but I 've noticed that i still get some strange outputs, for example I get this:

    [0,983507446704365 -5,48047057272053 -5,67846819076906 -2,72191629351606 -6,78646865534273 -5,47806115661807]

0.98xxx is the predicted class. I expected the sum of the vector to be 1.

Comment: The values of the SVMs do not sum up to 1. If you need this property, you must enforce it yourself. And it looks like you got distances from the hyperplane (since they are negativ) instead of probabilities. If you want those instead you must train the SVM with the b switch to apply [Platt's algorithm](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=69187).